# passing an unnamed object as an argument when making a new object in C++

Tags: c++

I want to use unnamed object as an argument in constructor, but it generates the following error.

I guess object name 'b2' is interpreted as function prototype or something.

```
class AAA
{
private:
    int m_val;
public:
    AAA(int a) : m_val(a) {}
};

class BBB
{
private:
    AAA a;
public:
    BBB(AAA &a_) : a(a_) {}
};

int main()
{
    AAA a(5), a1(10);
    BBB b(a), b1(a1);
    b = b1;
    BBB b2(AAA());
    b = b2;
}
```

```
.\ex_unnamed.cpp: In function 'int main()':  
.\ex_unnamed.cpp:21:9: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'BBB' and 'BBB(AAA (*)())')  
     b = b2;  
         ^~  
.\ex_unnamed.cpp:8:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr BBB& BBB::operator=(const BBB&)'  
 class BBB  
       ^~~  
.\ex_unnamed.cpp:8:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'BBB(AAA (*)())' to 'const BBB&'  
.\ex_unnamed.cpp:8:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr BBB& BBB::operator=(BBB&&)'  
.\ex_unnamed.cpp:8:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'BBB(AAA (*)())' to 'BBB&&'
```

Comment: You're not allowed to modify a temporary object.  `BBB(AAA &a_)` says "I'm going to modify `a_`."  Which you can't do with a temporary object.

Comment: you should make everything `const` be default. Only if `B`s constructor does need to modify its parameter it should be passed by non-const reference. Maybe then it is also easier to understand why C++ does not allow you to bind the temporary to the `AAA&` reference: If a method need some modifications to be visible on its parameters then it does not make sense to pass a temporary (because then the modifications are not visible)

Comment: Get used to adding `const` everywhere. It's important.

Comment: Actually, since `BBB` takes **ownership** of `a_`, the best approach here would be `BBB(AAA a_) : a(std::move(a_)) {}`. No const needed in this case.

Comment: @Frank `BBB(AAA &&a_) : a(std::move(a_)) {}` would also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, this does not mean what you think it means:

```
BBB b2( AAA() );
```

`b2` is actually interpreted by the compiler as a declaration of a function called `b2` which takes a function pointer which returns an `AAA` as a parameter, and which returns a `BBB`.

For my compiler, look at the signature:

[image]

So then this fails:

```
b = b2;
```

because `BBB` does not have an assignment operator which takes a function, etc.

You can fix this by doing this:

```
int main()
{
    AAA a(5), a1(10);
    BBB b(a), b1(a1);
    b = b1;
    BBB b2( AAA(5) );
    b = b2;
}
```

BUT it will still not compile. This is because `BBB` requires a reference to an actual `AAA` object.

To fix this, since you are not actually changing the `AAA` object passed, I recommend that you change the constructor of `BBB` to this:

```
BBB(const AAA& a_) : a(a_) {}
```

After all, `BBB::a` is just a copy of the parameter passed in `BBB`'s contructor. The final result:

```
class AAA
{
private:
    int m_val;
public:
    AAA(int a) : m_val(a) {}
};

class BBB
{
private:
    AAA a;
public:
    BBB(const AAA& a_) : a(a_) {}
};

int main()
{
    AAA a(5), a1(10);
    BBB b(a), b1(a1);
    b = b1;
    BBB b2( AAA(5) );
    b = b2;
}
```

It works!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My original intention at the statement `BBB b2( AAA() )` was to declare b2 as object not function pointer. I got to know that `BBB b2(AAA{})` is what I want. I heard this is called 'C++ most vexing parse' ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)) After modifying this, I added `AAA() : m_val(0) {}` and `BBB(const AAA &a_) : a(a_) {}`.

Comment: @EUNWOOLEE, great!